# Show posts by all users on my page's Facebook timeline by default

Tags: facebook, facebook-pages

I've created a Facebook page for a community, and I want to make it so that posts by others are shown by default when someone visits the page. Currently, it is only showing posts made by me-as-admin, until someone clicks the "Posts by Others" button (and then it doesn't show mine-as-admin; also undesirable). Is there a way of doing this, without having to manually make every single post a highlight?

Answer (score -1):

When you visit your Facebook Page, click *Edit Page* then select *Manage Permissions*.

From here you can set default visibility on the timeline for your users posts.

Comment: Still all post by others on my pages are not visible on my page

Comment: It is not possible.

Answer (score -1):

You have to enable Post Visibility (Show the box for "Recent Posts by Others") on your page.

1. Go to page (You're admin of)
2. Click 'Edit Page'
3. Select 'Manage Permissions'
4. Then tick/check Post Visibility: Show the box for "Recent Posts by Others"

[image: #Screenshot of Settings]